# <Color Style> in HTML in Option... Correct Way?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to use an option with style for COLORS.
Thus, I have used the code as below:

```
<option style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">&#9724; Dark blue</option>
```

However, the Color for $#9724 comes in black. It should be DARK BLUE. I thought this style and color is just used without any CSS being brought.

Am I missing something?
I am trying to learn what Jamel Baz mentioned.
http://jamelbaz.com/tutos/integration-de-fullcalendar2-php-mysql

All seems to be working, but not the color in the modal view.

Anyway, the link was for the reference.

Is my syntax incorrect to bring the color?

Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not apply style "color" & "background-color" to `<option>` element, it's rendered by OS not browser, see this:

[How to style the option of a html "select"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)